# How to use different EntityManager based on condition at runtime?

Tags: jpa, ejb, cdi

My congfiguration is like below:

The abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    // other methods create(T), edit(T), ...
```

The Ejb that extends the abstract class (i have many others EJBs and about 12 different persistence units):

```
@Stateless
public class FilesDao extends AbstractFacade<Files> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myfirstPU")
    private EntityManager firstEm;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "mysecondPU")
    private EntityManager secondEm;

    // i have more than two persistenceUnit ... 

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
         return firstEm; // or secondEm based on condition
    }

    public FilesDao() {
         super(Files.class);
    }

    public Files findByFileref(String inFileRef) {
         try {
             Query q = firstEm.createNamedQuery("Files.findByFileref"); // or secondEm based on condition
             q.setParameter("fileref", inFileRef);
             Files file = (Files) q.getSingleResult();
             return file;
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
             return null;
        }
    }
```

I want to use FilesDao like this :

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class FileBusiness {

    @EJB
    FilesDao fileDao;

    public void myMethod(){
    if(condition1){
         //use the FileDao with the EnityManager **firstEm**
    }
    else if(condition2){
        //use the FileDao with the EnityManager **secondtEm**
    }
    ...

}
```

Is there a way to achieve that ?

I read about using CDI with produces method.

Comment: Since it seems you need to dynamically decide which one EM to choose on every call, I would simply redesign `AbstractFacade.getEntityManager()` to take an argument of the condition and based on that return the relevant EM. CDI producers won't probably help you here as those are for when you need, _upon injection_ decide what to inject (whereas you need to dynamically choose different one every time).

Answer (score 0):

CDI-Producers are not that hard, see the following example.

The following classes are CDI-Qualifier annotations, which are used to distinguish implementations.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR }) 
@Qualifier 
public @interface MyfirstPUQualifier {  }

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR }) 
@Qualifier 
public @interface MysecondPUQualifier {  }
```

The following is a CDI-Bean which injects the different EntityManagers and implements producer methods, making the two EntityManagers available to CDI, distinguished via CDI-Qualifiers

```
@ApplicationScoped
class MYProducer {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myfirstPU")
    private EntityManager firstEm;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "mysecondPU")
    private EntityManager secondEm;

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    @MyfirstPUQualifier
    public EntityManager produceMyfirstPU(){
        return firstEm;
    }


    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    @MysecondPUQualifier
    public EntityManager produceMysecondPU(){
        return secondEm;
    }
}
```

The following shows a CDI-Bean injecting both EntityManagers. This could be extracted to an abstract base class, because maybe needed by other DAOs as well.

```
@Stateless
public class FileDao {

    @Inject
    @MyfirstPUQualifier
    private EntityManager emFirst;

    @Inject
    @MysecondPUQualifier
    private EntityManager emSecond;

    public void myDaoMEthod(){
        final EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        ...
    }

    private EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        if(condition1){
            return emFirst;
        }
        else if(condition2){
            return emSecond;
        }
    }
}
```

No can use the FileDao bean without taking care what EntityManager to use, because shouldn't be decided in this bean anyway

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class FileBusiness {

    @EJB
    FilesDao fileDao;

    public void myMethod(){
        // FileDao will decide what entity manager to use
        fileDao.doStruff();
    }
}
```